# Problem getting license libraries of my app

Tags: android, kotlin, open-source, libraries, licensing

i have built an Android application in Kotlin and used various libraries including `androidx.camera`, `com.google.android.gms`, `info.debatty`, `androidx.core`, and `androidx.appcompat`, among others.
My concern is whether these libraries are open source and royalty-free or if I may receive a payment request from Google or someone else for their use.
I cannot remove the application from a user's smartphone, so i need confirmation of licenses and royalties before publishing it on the Play Store.

I've listed the complete list of licenses for third-party dependencies from my app using the OSS Licenses plugin (https://johncodeos.com/how-to-list-third-party-dependencies-licenses-in-your-android-app/). However, when I checked the "Kotlin" library using this plugin, it returned a mix of incompatible NPL and GPL licenses, and I do not understand why.

Here are the libraries used in my application:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
//Add Text Recognition Google ML Library
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common:18.0.0'
implementation("info.debatty:java-string-similarity:2.0.0")
```

And here are all the licenses for third-party dependencies:

> ```
> https://opensource.org/license/mit/
> https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
> https://developer.android.com/studio/terms
> https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
> https://github.com/mojohaus/animal-sniffer/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/main/README.chromium
> https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://github.com/amaembo/jsr-305/blob/master/ri/LICENSE
> https://github.com/google/jsinterop-annotations/blob/master/LICENSE
> ```

**KOTLIN LIBRARIE THAT EXTRACT ALL THIS LICENSE - START**

> ```
> https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/license/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-deps-trove4j/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://www-archive.mozilla.org/mpl/npl-1.1
> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/1.1/
> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/
> https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
> https://github.com/stephengold/asm/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt
> https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
> ```

**KOTLIN LIBRARIE THAT EXTRACT ALL THIS LICENSE - END**

> ```
> https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms
> https://developers.google.com/terms
> https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html
> ```

Thank you!
Massimo

Comment: Most of the libraries are by the GNU (I think) license. Which means if they given on an open source platform then they are free to use. Unless you specifically bought the right to use them. A library is just a library. So therefore they are for use for the public. I have libraries that are closed sourced that is not available to the public. In that event you would have to have permission since it’s closed sourced. Open sourced libraries are free to use.

Comment: Thanks @CampNerd
My finally list it's the one below:

https://opensource.org/license/mit/ https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt https://developer.android.com/studio/terms https://github.com/mojohaus/animal-sniffer/blob/master/LICENSE https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/main/README.chromium https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/LICENSE.txt https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/LICENSE https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms
https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms

Do you think these license could give me some troubles if i publish my app?

Many thanks.
Massimo

Comment: This is Google Developer side....Subject to the terms of the License Agreement, Google grants you a limited, worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable, non-exclusive, and non-sublicensable license to use the SDK solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android...... So anything from Google you don't need a license

Comment: I also posted it as an answer for both GitHub and Google Developer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer to the Question and this by the polices of each GitHub and Google Developer..

> GitHub
> Public repositories on GitHub are often used to share open source software. For your repository to truly be open source, you'll need to license it so that others are free to use, change, and distribute the software.
>
> Google Developer
> Subject to the terms of the License Agreement, Google grants you a limited, worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable, non-exclusive, and non-sublicensable license to use the SDK solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android...... So anything from Google you don't need a license

So therefore you don't need to retain a licenses. If the dependency is not available for open source or is public for use, then you would have to purchase it retain a licensing use for commercial.

So anything from GitHub or Google Developer is free to use for commercial or personal use without restrictions.